# How to Increase RAM usage without increasing Cache.?

Tags: linux, memory-management

Amount of memory utilized in RAM is getting stored in Cache . Is there any way to manually increase RAM usage without increasing cache. 
Below the sample where increasing RAM is also increasing cache.

```
Mem:   3924040k total,  1396308k used,  2527732k free,    74224k buffers
Swap:  4063228k total,        0k used,  4063228k free,   512984k cached

                (Consuming 1GB of RAM by filling shared memory space)
                [root@localhost ~]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/shm/fill bs=1k count=1024k

After  
Mem:   3924040k total,  2447640k used,  1476400k free,    74248k buffers
Swap:  4063228k total,        0k used,  4063228k free,  1561652k cached
```

Comment: Do you want to reduce the cache usage?

Comment: To simulate memory usage i want increase RAM utilization without increasing cache memory. Below is example where i am trying to increase RAM by putting data into shared memory but same amount of cache is getting increase. I want avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

The default value is 60. If you set it to 0 means it will never use cache even RAM utilized 100%.

To check current level of swapiness,

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

To change the default value,

```
echo 10 > /proc/sys/vm/swapiness ( lost on reboot )

vim /etc/sysctl.conf  ( Permanent solution )
vm.swappiness = 10
```

Comment: coudn't help Ebin. I tried as per your suggestion.

Before :
'[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        3924040 kB
MemFree:         2794880 kB
Buffers:           58132 kB
Cached:           281124 kB
'
Writing into RAM:
[root@localhost ~]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/shm/fill bs=1k count=1024k

After Writing into RAM:
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        3924040 kB
MemFree:         1743216 kB
Buffers:           58236 kB
Cached:          1330096 kB'